# org.hibernate.query.SemanticException: Could not resolve attribute

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

When i query ` the sql bellow the error keep showing

```
search = session.createQuery("FROM QLKH_DTO a WHERE a.Fullname LIKE :temp", QLKH_DTO.class)
                .setParameter("temp",temp)
                .list();
```

`However if it just like this then it does work`

```
  search = session.createQuery("FROM QLKH_DTO", QLKH_DTO.class)
                .list();
```

`Here my entity class QLKH_DTO`

```
package DTO;

import jakarta.persistence.Column;
import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import jakarta.persistence.GenerationType;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;
import jakarta.persistence.Table;


@Entity
@Table(name = "customers", catalog = "market")

public class QLKH_DTO implements java.io.Serializable {
    private Integer CustomerID;
    private String Password;
    private String Fullname; 
    private String Address;
    private String City;
    
    public QLKH_DTO(){}
     public QLKH_DTO(String Password,String Fullname, String Address, String City) {
        this.Password = Password;
        this.Fullname = Fullname;
        this.Address = Address;
        this.City = City;
    }
     
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy =GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "CustomerID")
    public Integer getCustomerID() {
        return CustomerID;
    }

    public void setCustomerID(Integer CustomerID) {
        this.CustomerID = CustomerID;
    }
    @Column(name = "Password")
    public String getPassword() {
        return Password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String Password) {
        this.Password = Password;
    }
    @Column(name = "Fullname")
    public String getFullname() {
        return Fullname;
    }

    public void setFullname(String Fullname) {
        this.Fullname = Fullname;
    }
    @Column(name = "Address", length = 20)
    public String getAddress() {
        return Address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String Address) {
        this.Address = Address;
    }
    @Column(name = "City", length = 20)
    public String getCity() {
        return City;
    }

    public void setCity(String City) {
        this.City = City;
    }
   
}
```

`The HibernateUtil class`

```
package utils;
 
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.boot.Metadata;
import org.hibernate.boot.MetadataSources;
import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder;
import org.hibernate.service.ServiceRegistry;
 
public class HibernateUtil {
    private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory = buildSessionFactory();
    public static SessionFactory buildSessionFactory() {
        try {
            ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry;
            serviceRegistry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder()
                    .configure()
                    .build();
            Metadata metadata = new MetadataSources(serviceRegistry)                                     
                        .getMetadataBuilder().build();
            return metadata.getSessionFactoryBuilder().build();
        } catch (Throwable ex) {
        }
        return sessionFactory;
    }
    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;
    }
}

;
```

`The test class`

```
package GUI.QLKH;


import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
 
import DTO.QLKH_DTO;
import java.util.List;
import utils.HibernateUtil;
 
public class QLKH {
    private static SessionFactory factory;
    Session session=null;
   // Transaction txn = null;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        factory = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();
        QLKH Customer = new QLKH();
       
        System.out.println("search customers:");
        Customer.search();
}
     public void search(){
         String temp="John";
         session = factory.openSession();
         session.beginTransaction(); 
        List<QLKH_DTO> search;
        search = session.createQuery("FROM QLKH_DTO a WHERE a.Fullname LIKE :temp", QLKH_DTO.class)
                .setParameter("temp",temp)
                .list();
        
        session.getTransaction().commit();      
        
        for (QLKH_DTO customer : search) {
            System.out.print("Password: " + customer.getPassword());
            System.out.print("Fullname: " + customer.getFullname());
            System.out.println("Address: " + customer.getAddress());
            System.out.println("City: " + customer.getCity());
        }
        
     }
}
```

`The sql`

```
CREATE TABLE `Customers` (
  `CustomerID` int(10) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `Password` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `Fullname` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  `Address` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `City` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (CustomerID)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

--
-- Dumping data for table `Customers`
--

INSERT INTO `Customers` (`CustomerID`, `Password`, `Fullname`, `Address`, `City`) VALUES
(1, 'Abcd1234', 'John Smith', '30 Broadway', 'London'),
(2, 'Abcd1234', 'Jonny English', '99 River View', 'Reading'),
(3, 'Abcd1234', 'Elizabeth', '23 Buckinghamshire', 'York'),
(4, 'Abcd1234', 'Beatrix', '66 Royal Crescent', 'Bath');
```

`Hibernate.cfg.xml`

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration SYSTEM 
"http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
   <session-factory>
   
      <property name = "hibernate.dialect">
         org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
      </property>
   
      <property name = "hibernate.connection.driver_class">
         com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
      </property>

      <!-- Assume students is the database name -->
   
      <property name = "hibernate.connection.url">
          jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/market
      </property>
   
      <property name = "hibernate.connection.username">
         root
      </property>
   
      <property name = "hibernate.connection.password">
         
      </property>
    <mapping class="DTO.QLKH_DTO" />
   </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

`And the error log`

```
cd C:\Users\MyPC\Documents\NetBeansProjects\QLKH; "JAVA_HOME=C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk-14.0.1" cmd /c "\"C:\\Program Files\\NetBeans-15\\netbeans\\java\\maven\\bin\\mvn.cmd\" -Dexec.vmArgs= \"-Dexec.args=${exec.vmArgs} -classpath %classpath ${exec.mainClass} ${exec.appArgs}\" \"-Dexec.executable=C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk-14.0.1\\bin\\java.exe\" -Dexec.mainClass=GUI.QLKH.QLKH -Dexec.classpathScope=runtime -Dexec.appArgs= \"-Dmaven.ext.class.path=C:\\Program Files\\NetBeans-15\\netbeans\\java\\maven-nblib\\netbeans-eventspy.jar\" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:3.0.0:exec"
Running NetBeans Compile On Save execution. Phase execution is skipped and output directories of dependency projects (with Compile on Save turned on) will be used instead of their jar artifacts.
Scanning for projects...

------------------------------< GUI:QLKH >------------------------------
Building QLKH 1.0
--------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------

--- exec-maven-plugin:3.0.0:exec (default-cli) @ QLKH ---
Nov 22, 2022 9:55:29 AM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 6.1.5.Final
Nov 22, 2022 9:55:31 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
WARN: HHH10001002: Using built-in connection pool (not intended for production use)
Nov 22, 2022 9:55:31 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001005: Loaded JDBC driver class: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
Nov 22, 2022 9:55:31 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001012: Connecting with JDBC URL [jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/market]
Nov 22, 2022 9:55:31 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001001: Connection properties: {password=****, user=root}
Nov 22, 2022 9:55:31 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001003: Autocommit mode: false
Nov 22, 2022 9:55:31 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl$PooledConnections <init>
INFO: HHH10001115: Connection pool size: 20 (min=1)
Nov 22, 2022 9:55:32 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.dialect.internal.DialectFactoryImpl logSelectedDialect
INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
Nov 22, 2022 9:55:35 AM org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.JtaPlatformInitiator initiateService
INFO: HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
search customers:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.query.sqm.InterpretationException: Error interpreting query [FROM QLKH_DTO a WHERE a.Fullname LIKE :temp]; this may indicate a semantic (user query) problem or a bug in the parser [FROM QLKH_DTO a WHERE a.Fullname LIKE :temp]
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:141)
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:175)
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:182)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:761)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:127)
    at GUI.QLKH.QLKH.search(QLKH.java:28)
    at GUI.QLKH.QLKH.main(QLKH.java:21)
Caused by: org.hibernate.query.sqm.InterpretationException: Error interpreting query [FROM QLKH_DTO a WHERE a.Fullname LIKE :temp]; this may indicate a semantic (user query) problem or a bug in the parser [FROM QLKH_DTO a WHERE a.Fullname LIKE :temp]
    at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.StandardHqlTranslator.translate(StandardHqlTranslator.java:97)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.lambda$createQuery$2(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:748)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.QueryInterpretationCacheStandardImpl.createHqlInterpretation(QueryInterpretationCacheStandardImpl.java:141)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.QueryInterpretationCacheStandardImpl.resolveHqlInterpretation(QueryInterpretationCacheStandardImpl.java:128)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:745)
    ... 3 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.query.SemanticException: Could not resolve attribute 'Fullname' of 'DTO.QLKH_DTO'
    at org.hibernate.query.sqm.SqmPathSource.getSubPathSource(SqmPathSource.java:61)
    at org.hibernate.query.sqm.tree.domain.AbstractSqmPath.get(AbstractSqmPath.java:160)
    at org.hibernate.query.sqm.tree.domain.AbstractSqmFrom.resolvePathPart(AbstractSqmFrom.java:192)
    at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.DomainPathPart.resolvePathPart(DomainPathPart.java:42)
    at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.BasicDotIdentifierConsumer.consumeIdentifier(BasicDotIdentifierConsumer.java:91)
    at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.SemanticQueryBuilder.visitSimplePath(SemanticQueryBuilder.java:4808)
    at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.SemanticQueryBuilder.visitIndexedPathAccessFragment(SemanticQueryBuilder.java:4755)
    at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.SemanticQueryBuilder.visitGeneralPathFragment(SemanticQueryBuilder.java:4724)
    at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.SemanticQueryBuilder.visitGeneralPathExpression(SemanticQueryBuilder.java:1423)
    at org.hibernate.grammars.hql.HqlParser$GeneralPathExpressionContext.accept(HqlParser.java:6963)
    at org.antlr.v4.runtime.tree.AbstractParseTreeVisitor.visitChildren(AbstractParseTreeVisitor.java:46)
    at org.hibernate.grammars.hql.HqlParserBaseVisitor.visitBarePrimaryExpression(HqlParserBaseVisitor.java:671)
    at org.hibernate.grammars.hql.HqlParser$BarePrimaryExpressionContext.accept(HqlParser.java:6437)
    at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.SemanticQueryBuilder.visitLikePredicate(SemanticQueryBuilder.java:2217)
    at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.SemanticQueryBuilder.visitLikePredicate(SemanticQueryBuilder.java:243)
    at org.hibernate.grammars.hql.HqlParser$LikePredicateContext.accept(HqlParser.java:5442)
    at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.SemanticQueryBuilder.visitWhereClause(SemanticQueryBuilder.java:1949)
    at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.SemanticQueryBuilder.visitWhereClause(SemanticQueryBuilder.java:243)
    at org.hibernate.grammars.hql.HqlParser$WhereClauseContext.accept(HqlParser.java:5290)
    at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.SemanticQueryBuilder.visitQuery(SemanticQueryBuilder.java:857)
    at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.SemanticQueryBuilder.visitQuerySpecExpression(SemanticQueryBuilder.java:629)
    at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.SemanticQueryBuilder.visitQuerySpecExpression(SemanticQueryBuilder.java:243)
    at org.hibernate.grammars.hql.HqlParser$QuerySpecExpressionContext.accept(HqlParser.java:1218)
    at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.SemanticQueryBuilder.visitSimpleQueryGroup(SemanticQueryBuilder.java:623)
    at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.SemanticQueryBuilder.visitSimpleQueryGroup(SemanticQueryBuilder.java:243)
    at org.hibernate.grammars.hql.HqlParser$SimpleQueryGroupContext.accept(HqlParser.java:1131)
    at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.SemanticQueryBuilder.visitSelectStatement(SemanticQueryBuilder.java:399)
    at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.SemanticQueryBuilder.visitStatement(SemanticQueryBuilder.java:358)
    at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.SemanticQueryBuilder.buildSemanticModel(SemanticQueryBuilder.java:285)
    at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.StandardHqlTranslator.translate(StandardHqlTranslator.java:81)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.query.SemanticException: Could not resolve attribute 'Fullname' of 'DTO.QLKH_DTO'
    ... 37 more
Command execution failed.
org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1)
    at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.executeInternal (DefaultExecutor.java:404)
    at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.execute (DefaultExecutor.java:166)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecMojo.executeCommandLine (ExecMojo.java:982)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecMojo.executeCommandLine (ExecMojo.java:929)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecMojo.execute (ExecMojo.java:457)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute2 (MojoExecutor.java:370)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute (MojoExecutor.java:351)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:215)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:171)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:163)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:294)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:960)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:293)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:196)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:564)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
------------------------------------------------------------------------
BUILD FAILURE
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total time:  12.026 s
Finished at: 2022-11-22T09:55:37+07:00
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:3.0.0:exec (default-cli) on project QLKH: Command execution failed.: Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1) -> [Help 1]

To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.

For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

`

I don't know what wrong,i have try another propety like City,Password and it could not reslove the propety too.Eventhough make the propety name and name in database the same to avoid error

Comment: `FROM QLKH_DTO a WHERE a.Fullname LIKE :temp` - shouldn't it be `SELECT a FROM QLKH_DTO a WHERE a.Fullname LIKE :temp`?

Comment: i want a whole entity not just a record

Comment: and it does not work too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem,it because I tagged the @column in the wrong place

```
@Table(name = "customers", catalog = "market")

public class QLKH_DTO implements java.io.Serializable {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy =GenerationType.IDENTITY) 
    @Column(name = "CustomerID")
    private Integer CustomerID;
   
    @Column(name = "Password")
    private String Password;
    
    @Column(name = "Fullname")
    private String Fullname; 
    
    @Column(name = "Address")
    private String Address;
    
    @Column(name = "City")
    private String City;
    
    public QLKH_DTO(){}
     
    public QLKH_DTO(String Password,String Fullname, String Address, String City) {
        this.Password = Password;
        this.Fullname = Fullname;
        this.Address = Address;
        this.City = City;
    }
     
 
    public Integer getCustomerID() {
        return this.CustomerID;
    }

    public void setCustomerID(Integer CustomerID) {
        this.CustomerID = CustomerID;
    }
    
    public String getPassword() {
        return this.Password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String Password) {
        this.Password = Password;
    }
   
    public String getFullname() {
        return this.Fullname;
    }

    public void setFullname(String Fullname) {
        this.Fullname = Fullname;
    }
    
    public String getAddress() {
        return this.Address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String Address) {
        this.Address = Address;
    }
   
    public String getCity() {
        return this.City;
    }

    public void setCity(String City) {
        this.City = City;
    } 
}
```

Comment: I have same kind of problem. Why do you say that @Column is in the wrong place?

Comment: Tag the @column before the defining of attribute

Comment: @Column(name = "Password")
    private String Password;